# Saying "ModelViewViewModel" or "MVVM" out loud is too awkward! Alternatives?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

This may seem really silly to you, I admit, but when discussing the Model-View-ViewModel pattern with my teammates, it's very awkward to pronounce the term. "ModelViewViewModel" or "Emm-Vee-Vee-Emm" don't exactly roll off the tongue. Especially when you're not a native English speaker.

So I'm looking for an alternative. Something quick and easy to say.

Current suggestions are:

M2VM - "emm two vee emm" (feels smoother to say) 
M2V2 - "emm two vee two" (doesn't quite fit, but it's inspired by H2G2 :))

Any more ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I think MVVM sounds better than both of the suggestions. I usually manage to discuss the pattern without saying it's name though.

Comment: Someone suggested "Emm-Vees-Emm", which I thought wasn't bad at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not say "Move-em" instead of MVVM. When answering someones question about pattern to use, you could then simply answer "We can Move-em".

Answer (score 2):

Pretend the Vs are a W, which is really 2 Us let's be fair, and say **Muum**. Bonus points for doing it like a cow.